# Spring implementation of Flyweight pattern

Tags: spring, design-patterns, javabeans, flyweight-pattern

I have a Flyweight pattern implementation in java programming without Spring. Please suggest how do I make this as a Spring managed Bean. It has static method calls and Inner class. The purpose is to initially load all the OptionSets from CRM to share the same OptionSets in the application. This prevents expensive calls to CRM. Users are restricted to create any new OptionSets hence Inner class. First need to implement as a Spring bean and then get it to be ApplicationContextAware to reference other beans. I am primarily using Spring XML configuration for bean definition.

```
public class OptionSetFactory{
    private static Map <String, Object>optionSets = new HashMap();

    //Inner class to restrict users creating OptionSet
    private class OptionSet implements IOptionSet{
        private String entityName;
        private String attributeName;
        private Hashtable<Integer, String> options;
        private IOrganizationService service;
        private static final String GUID_EMPTY = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
        private ApplicationContext context;

        OptionSet(String entityName, String attributeName){
            this.entityName = entityName;
            this.attributeName = attributeName;
            //this.options = options;   

            OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest();            
            request.setRequestName("RetrieveAttribute");            
            Guid guid = new Guid();
            guid.setValue(GUID_EMPTY);                  
            ParameterCollection paramCol = new ParameterCollection();
            KeyValuePairOfstringanyType kv0 = new KeyValuePairOfstringanyType();
            kv0.setKey("MetadataId");
            kv0.setValue(guid);
            paramCol.getKeyValuePairOfstringanyTypes().add(kv0);

            KeyValuePairOfstringanyType kv1 = new KeyValuePairOfstringanyType();
            kv1.setKey("EntityLogicalName");
            kv1.setValue(entityName);
            paramCol.getKeyValuePairOfstringanyTypes().add(kv1);
            KeyValuePairOfstringanyType kv2 = new KeyValuePairOfstringanyType();
            kv2.setKey("LogicalName");
            kv2.setValue(attributeName);
            paramCol.getKeyValuePairOfstringanyTypes().add(kv2);
            KeyValuePairOfstringanyType kv3 = new KeyValuePairOfstringanyType();
            kv3.setKey("RetrieveAsIfPublished");
            kv3.setValue(true);
            paramCol.getKeyValuePairOfstringanyTypes().add(kv3);
            request.setParameters(paramCol);
            try {
                OrganizationResponse response=service.execute(request);
                PicklistAttributeMetadata pickListAttrMetadata = (PicklistAttributeMetadata)response.getResults().getKeyValuePairOfstringanyTypes().get(0).getValue();
                OptionSetMetadata optionSetMetadata = pickListAttrMetadata.getOptionSet();
                for(OptionMetadata optionMetaData : optionSetMetadata.getOptions().getOptionMetadatas()){
                    //TODO populate OptionSet from optionsetMetadata
                }
            } catch (IOrganizationServiceExecuteOrganizationServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getEntityName() {
            return entityName;
        }

        @Override
        public String getAttributeName() {
            return attributeName;
        }

        @Override
        public Hashtable<Integer, String> getOptions() {
            return options;
        }
    }
    //static block to load predefined OptionSets in HashMap
    static{
        OptionSetFactory factory = new OptionSetFactory();
        optionSets.put("dsl_type", factory.new OptionSet("dsl_type", "dsl_operationalstructure"));

    }
    //Static method calls for user to fetch OptionSet based on inputs
    public static IOptionSet getOptionSet(String entityName, String attributeName){
        return (IOptionSet) optionSets.get(entityName+"."+attributeName);
    }

    public static IOptionSet getOptionSet(String attributeName){
        return (IOptionSet) optionSets.get(attributeName.toLowerCase());        
    }
}
```

Comment: looks to me like if you removed all of the occurrences of "static" in this file, it should be perfectly manageable by Spring

Comment: Hi Sean, I cannot quite visualize it. What about the static initializer and static HashMap. Is it possible to post the bean definition in the above case

Comment: yes, make the initializer and instance initializer and the hashmap non-static, and everything should work

Comment: Please post the bean definition as you see it working, I will try it and let you know.